# Using Bash script to get substring with ${parameter##word}

Tags: bash, parameters, substring

Just as the title says, I'm trying to write a bash script to get a substring.  Most (all?) of the examples of the ${parameter##word} I found online split using one character, but I want to split using a substring?
For example, why wouldn't this work:

```
str="this is the original"
substr="is the"
echo ${str##substr}
```

With the output being "original"

Comment: `echo "${str##*$substr}"`?

Comment: It's not clear to me if you're trying to _split_ or trying to _find a substring_. Those are different things, with different results. Nevertheless, to get `original` you'd want `${str##*$substr}`: you need the `*` to consume all the characters occurring prior to the split string.

Comment: `##` removes the longest string on the left that matches the *pattern* (so the asterisk goes on the left), `#` removes the shortest.  `%%` removes the longest string on the right that matches the pattern (so the asterisk goes on the right), `%` removes the shortest.